# Angular 2 - Inline app

Tags: angular

I am getting my feet wet with Angular 2 (javascript). I have just a plain index.html file. I want to include all of my code for my app in my index.html file. Can you do this? This seems like it would be the most straightforward approach. However, all of the examples I see are pulling files from all of the place.

I want to create a basic "hello world" with all of my code in index.html. Can this be done with Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to follow a tutorial. There's not many out there but check out https://angular.io/ on the offical Angular2 site.

MS & Google would prefer the use of TypeScript or JS (ES2015) with Angular 2. They compile to the current ES5 standard. You can use native ES5 with Angular 2 I'm not familiar with the set up, but why would you want to?

I recommend to go along with the usage Angular is promoting for simplicity, to avoid disappointments and because learning resources are easier to find that way.

Long story short, **realistically** you can't just drop everything in a HTML file. Ideally you need to follow the new process.